# How can I make a for loop to load images to my application using C#?

Tags: c#, image

I have an application that I need to load some images from my folder to the application as a bmp bitmap image and for that purpose I am using the following code:

Then I need to iterate throw each images line by line and make a separate list for each image (list1, list2, etc.) which contains only zero and ones (the images are only black and white)

My problem is for finite number of images I can copy the same code (for example for 5 images) five time, but for large number of images (for example 100 images) is not possible, I just wanted to know how to turn this code in a for loop that looks for a number of images (for example 100) and I get different lists (list1, list2, list3, etc.) as output.

Comment: Are you trying to show all 100 images (or however many there are) at the same time in 100 picture boxes?

Comment: yes that's right. but the main thing is to import them to the application in order to process them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all files in the path are Images you can do the following:

```
var images = new List<Bitmap>();
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
{
    string nextimage = files[i];
    Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.FromFile(nextimage) as Bitmap
    images.Add(bmp1); //to keep images in RAM for later process
    bmp1.Save(somePath + "\\bmp" + i.ToString()); // to save images on disc
}
```

And it's not a good idea to load (n) images one after each other, because you will only see the last one. So you'd better show one of them, for example:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(files[files.Count() - 1]) as Bitmap;
```

Comment: how can i save them as bmp1, bmp2, etc.?

Comment: @user3384676 I added the code for saving them with incremental name, just consider that your folder should not already have items with same names in it, otherwise you need to start the index from the last file name and also change your for condition a bit, that's easy.

Comment: i actually don't want to save the images, but i need to just to have them in my application s bmp1, bmp2, bmp3, etc. for later process.

Comment: @user3384676 keep them in a `List` or `Array`. I edited the answer with a List of Bitmaps, check it.

Comment: thank you Mahdi, that actually solved my first part of my question, do you have any idea about the second part part of question?;)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a collection of `Bitmap` objects, then just iterate through the files in the directory to load them all.  Perhaps something like this:

```
var images = new List<Bitmap>();
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myfolder\"))
    images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(file) as Bitmap);
```

You can optionally add [a filter and other options to `Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory.GetFiles.aspx) to narrow down the search, if the directory contains other files which you don't want to load as bitmaps.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but as i mentioned in my question i need to load images as bmp1, bmp2, etc. and display them in my picture box accordingly.

Comment: @user3384676: Then you need to declare each individual variable and load it one at a time.  For 100 images, that's going to be a lot of repeated code.  In that case, what's your question?

Comment: @user3384676: Well, if that code needs to be run for each image that's imported, then you'd wrap it in a loop which iterates over the collection of images.  That would replace `bmp1` with something like `images[i]` in the loop.